# How can I force Windows Phone 8 to renew the wifi DHCP lease?

Tags: windows-phone-8

My DCHP server have a long TLL of the leases. We were forced to change the DNS IP in the network, and we are not able to force Windows Phone 8.1 (Lumia 730) to get a new lease.

Does anybody knows a way to do this?